# Maps autocomplete filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am currently using the [Google Maps Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), but I only need to show places that are either of [type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) `address` or `establishment`, but both cannot be combined this way. I have tried using [getPlacePredictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) and [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) with no succes.

Is it possible to use autocomplete to show a list of only the places that has one of these types? Of not, what are the alternatives? Could I perhaps create a custom autocomplete with typeahead?

Comment: @d.datul1990 I've added some details below your answer

Answer (score 0):

**The following example uses autocomplete to fill the fields in an address form.**

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
```

**Add SearchBox for autocompleting search terms**

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
  bounds: defaultBounds
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. Basically I just want to tell the API that I only need results that are of type 'address' or 'establishment'

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use the  [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction). As the user enters text, autocomplete returns place predictions in the form of a dropdown list. When the user selects a place from the list, information about the place is returned to the autocomplete object, and can be retrieved by your application

Autocomplete gives your applications the type-ahead-search behavior of the Google Maps search field. When a user starts typing an address, autocomplete will fill in the rest.

You may use this as your guide in creating autocomplete with typeahead.js: http://code.runnable.com/UlXgeluakNULAAAv/create-an-autocomplete-input-box-with-typeahead-js-for-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but autocomplete still returns all types of placeresults. My goal is to filter out all those which are *not* of type 'address' or 'establishment', because I cannot use those in my application. I have already solved this by fetching all results, and then filtering them manually by type, but this limits the amount of results that I can show to my users. So is it possible to let the autocomplete API do this filtering?

Comment: If I understand your question correct. You may check the places  search api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: Could you be more specific? An example would be appreciated